# MySQL Filter WHERE By Subselect Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with a subselect statement and I am looking for a way to use it in the where clause such as this:

```
SELECT      p.id as project_id, (
            SELECT      pfva.dateValue
            FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfva
            WHERE       (pfva.fieldKey = 'listing_date' AND p.id = project_id)
            LIMIT 1         
            ) as table_filter_date
FROM        Project p
JOIN        ProjectFieldValue pfv
 ON         p.id = pfv.project_id
WHERE       (fieldKey = 'contract_status' AND pfv.textValue IN ('Active'))
AND         table_filter_date BETWEEN '2020-06-06' AND '2020-12-12'
```

**This does not seem to work...**

```
AND table_filter_date BETWEEN '2020-06-06' AND '2020-12-12'
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Unknown column 'table_filter_date' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any way that I can use this value "table_filter_date" in a HAVING or FIND_IN_SET or some way in the WHERE. I basically need to be able to filter the results by this variable and a beginning and end date (using BETWEEN and AND) in some way.

Comment: What if you add between..and condition into subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *produce* this named column by including your query as a "table expression". For example:

```
select *
from ( -- table expression "x" starts
  SELECT    p.id as project_id, (
            SELECT      pfva.dateValue
            FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfva
            WHERE       (pfva.fieldKey = 'listing_date' AND p.id = project_id)
            LIMIT 1         
            ) as table_filter_date
  FROM      Project p
  JOIN      ProjectFieldValue pfv
   ON       p.id = pfv.project_id
  WHERE     (fieldKey = 'contract_status' AND pfv.textValue IN ('Active'))
) x -- table expression "x" ends
WHERE   table_filter_date BETWEEN '2020-06-06' AND '2020-12-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Store `table_filter_date` in a variable and use that in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT      p.id as project_id, ( @tfd := (
            SELECT      pfva.dateValue
            FROM        ProjectFieldValue pfva
            WHERE       (pfva.fieldKey = 'listing_date' AND p.id = project_id)
            LIMIT 1         
            ) ) as table_filter_date
FROM        Project p
JOIN        ProjectFieldValue pfv
 ON         p.id = pfv.project_id
WHERE       (fieldKey = 'contract_status' AND pfv.textValue IN ('Active'))
AND         @tfd BETWEEN '2020-06-06' AND '2020-12-12'
```